# JavaScript email validation contains specified address

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for javascript validation on email form field. On submit i want to validate if email contains @specifieddomain.com then submit else error message "please use your company email"

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

     <p><form id="microsubs_form" method="post" action="/" class="" >

        <input type="text" id="ms_firstName" required="true" placeholder="First Name" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
        <input type="text" id="ms_lastName" required="true" style="float:right; alignment-adjust:central; clear:right" placeholder="Last Name" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
        <input type="email" id="ms_email" required="true" style="float:left;" placeholder="Corporate Email address">
        <input type="number" id="ms_telephoneNumber" required="true" style="float:right; alignment-adjust:central; clear:right">


        </form></p>

        <p></p>

    </div>
</div>
```

thanks

Comment: HTML: `<input pattern="\\w+@specifieddomain\\.com"` JS: `emailValue.endsWith(@specifieddomain.com);`

Comment: This should not be a difficult web search and you are expected to do basic research before asking questions here

Comment: @charlietfl yes it is a easy websearch, but i am a software engineer not a developer and had a solution just seeing what is best out there as there is numerous different implementations.

Comment: Then the proper thing would be show what you already have...not ask as if no research had been done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) in HTML

change input email like this :

```
<input type="email" pattern="\w+@specifieddomain\.com" style="float:left;" placeholder="Corporate Email address">
```

final code :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

     <p><form id="microsubs_form" method="post" action="/" class="" >

        <input type="text" id="ms_firstName" required="true" placeholder="First Name" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
        <input type="text" id="ms_lastName" required="true" style="float:right; alignment-adjust:central; clear:right" placeholder="Last Name" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
        <input type="email" pattern="\w+@specifieddomain\.com" style="float:left;" placeholder="Corporate Email address">
        <input type="number" id="ms_telephoneNumber" required="true" style="float:right; alignment-adjust:central; clear:right">
        <input type="submit">
        </form>

        <p></p>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

2) in javascript

change form like this

```
<form id="microsubs_form" method="post" action="/" class="" onsubmit="return validEmail()" >
```

and use test Method,

```
<script>
           var emil = document.getElementById("email");
           var patt = /\w+@specifieddomain\.com/;
           function validEmail() {
               if (!patt.test(emil.value)) {
                   alert("please use your company email");
                   return false;
               }
               else
                   return true;
           }
       </script>
```

final code :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

     <p><form id="microsubs_form" method="post" action="/" class="" onsubmit="return validEmail()" >

        <input type="text" id="ms_firstName" required="true" placeholder="First Name" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
        <input type="text" id="ms_lastName" required="true" style="float:right; alignment-adjust:central; clear:right" placeholder="Last Name" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
        <input id="email" style="float:left;" placeholder="Corporate Email address">
        <input type="number" id="ms_telephoneNumber" required="true" style="float:right; alignment-adjust:central; clear:right">
        <input type="submit">
        </form>
        <p></p>
    </div>
       <script>
           var emil = document.getElementById("email");
           var patt = /\w+@specifieddomain\.com/;
           function validEmail() {
               if (!patt.test(emil.value)) {
                   alert("please use your company email");
                   return false;
               }
               else
                   return true;
           }
       </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: great solution, similar to what test version i had. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function emailvalidator(){
          var email = document.getElementById('ms_email').value;

          if(email.search("@yourdomain.com")!=-1){
                alert("wrong email"); 
          }else{
                alert("email is valid!");
          }
   }
</script>
```

add this function in your file, then call this function on submit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$('#microsubs_form').on('submit',function(){

    var email = $('#ms_email').val();
    var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }

})
```